# Linux heap allocation

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

In `FreeRTOS`, the heap is simply a global array with a size (lets call is `heapSize`) defined in a `H` file which the user can change. This array is a non-initialized global array which makes it as part of the `BSS` section of the image, as so it is filled with zeros upon loading, then, every allocation of memory is taken from this array and every address of allocated memory is a an offset of this array.

So, for a maximal utilization of the memory size, we can approximate the size of the `Data`, `Text` and `BSS` areas of our entire program, and define the heap size to something like `heapSize = RAM_size - Text_size - Data_size - BSS_size`.

I would like to know what is the equivalent implementation is Linux OS. Can Linux scan a given RAM and decide its size in run time? does linux have an equivalent data structure to manage the heap? if so, how does it allocates the memory for this data structure in the first place?

Comment: Linux' memory management is far to complex to be sufficiently described in the StackOverflow Q&A format. Most importantly Linux is a virtual memory OS, that separated address space in kernel and user land, with different memory allocation method for each.

Comment: http://www.johnchukwuma.com/training/UnderstandingTheLinuxKernel3rdEdition.pdf

Comment: Your program can read `/proc/meminfo` to determine the amount of real and used memory.

Comment: Linux allows allocation at page granularity (which is used for process memory and some large in-system memory areas) and structure/buffer granularity which uses one of the available allocators: SLAB/SLUB (which is actually not heap but a list of lists of blocks of the same size) and SLOB (much simpler, targeted or embedded).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know what is the equivalent implementation is Linux OS.

Read "Chapter 8: Allocating Memory" in [Linux Device Drivers, Third Edition](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/).

Answer (score 0):

Heaps in Linux are dynamic, so it grows whenever you request more memory. This can extend beyond physical memory size by using swap files, where some unused portions of the RAM is written to disk.

So I think you need to think more in terms of "how much memory does my application need" rather than "how much memory is available".